# javax.faces.viewstate view state problem in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance

i have made test cases in Jmeter and saved the test plan but when i restart my server and run those testplan i found the errors in samples that your session has expired and i got errors in jsf application due to  view state problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract the value of `javax.faces.viewstate` field (which is basically a hidden input in the response body) of previous request, convert it into a [JMeter Variable](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and add it as a parameter to the next request.

You can use one of the following PostProcessors for it:

- [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)
- [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor)
- [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)

The process of extracting dynamic data and reusing it later in the test script is known as [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations)

Don't forget to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your test plan as well, it automatically handles cookies and will handle and maintain the session for each virtual user